# Add role to user (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make discord bot to add a role to user who reacted to message in channel.
That is my code.

```
`const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions],
    partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction],
});
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Готов!");
});
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === '1030100801747701760') {
        console.log("Сработала реакция1");
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            const member = reaction.options.getMember(user.id);
            const role = reaction.options.getRole('1030138804830478387');
            member.roles.add(role);
        }
    }
});`
```

TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getMember'). - Error

I am a total newbie in discord.js and I do not quite understand how to get user and use it to give him a role. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `options` on a `MessageReaction`. That means that the function `reaction.options.getMember()` will return an error.
To fix this problem you need to search for the Member in the guild:
`reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);`
Also you can't use `reaction.options.getRole()` to get a Role from the Guild. To fix this you need to get it from the Guild again with `reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.get('1030138804830478387')`

**Working Code:**

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions],
    partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction],
});
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Готов!");
});
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === '1030100801747701760') {
        console.log("Сработала реакция1");
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            const member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
            const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.get('1030138804830478387');
            member.roles.add(role);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the error. This time it is something like that TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members').

Comment: edited it, now it should work

Comment: It is working perfectly! Thanks a lot, been struggling with this quite a while