# how to add role to user from an array?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a user from an array, how can I give him a role?

my code:

````
  if (interaction.customId == "buttoninvyes"+(i+1)) {
    const channelinv = "1173243142032609340"
    console.log(applicationList[i].id)
    client.channels.cache.get(channelinv).send(`${applicationList[i]}`);
    applicationList.split(i,1);
  }}

    })

    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
      if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        return;}
      applicationList.push(interaction.user)})```
````

Comment: Where is the role that you wish to add to the user? How do you determine the role you want to add? I also advise looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090662/add-role-to-user-discord-js?rq=2) question as it may have the answer you need